# R Markdown: how make I make inline code do not execute?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I want to write something like ***I used lm() function in R*** in R markdown and I wish to make the lm() stand out as it is a code.

I tried to use ***I used `r lm()` function*** method to make lm() stands out, but it won't work as the program keeps telling me that lm() needs a parameter.

Is there a way I can force the inline code just display and do not execute? Thank you!

Comment: Don't put the letter r.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `r` call.

Example (`.Rmd` file):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

I used the `lm()` function.
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't exactly stand out though (one would expect it to be highlighted in gray or something).